# Class not executing in Debug...?

Tags: debugging

I have a class which is invoked by Lightning Component action button. For some reason it does not seem to be executing the first part of the class in the debug log.

Here is the Lightning Component action button :

```
<aura:component controller='GetProgramCommunicationRecipientsRecords' implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <!-- Define attributes -->
    <aura:attribute name="listOfProgramCommunicationRep" type="List"  />
    
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <div class="slds-text-heading_small" align="center" >
        {!$Label.c.Send_Welcome_Email_Message}
    </div>
    <div class="slds-text-heading_small" align="center" >
        <lightning:dynamicIcon type="eq" option="play" alternativeText="On a call"/>
    </div>
    
</aura:component>
```

Here is the Helper in the Lightning Component :

```
({
    getProgramCommunicationRecipients: function(component, event){
        var action = component.get('c.getProgramRecipients');
        action.setParams({"recordId" : component.get('v.recordId')});
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set('v.listOfProgramCommunicationRep', response.getReturnValue());
                console.log("Program communication recipients"+JSON.stringify(component.get('v.listOfProgramCommunicationRep')));
                this.sendEmailToAllProgramComRec(component, event);
            } else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
                var resMsg = "From server: " + response.getReturnValue();
                var resType = 'Error';
                this.showToast(component, event, helper, resMsg, resType);
                //alert("From server: " + response.getReturnValue());
            } else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        var resMsg = "Error message: " + errors[0].message;
                        var resType = 'Error';
                        this.showToast(component, event, helper, resMsg, resType);
                        //console.log("Error message: " + errors[0].message);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("Unknown error");
                }
            }
        });
        // enqueue the action
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
        
    },
    sendEmailToAllProgramComRec: function(component, event){
        console.log("Program communication recipients after doInit"+JSON.stringify(component.get('v.listOfProgramCommunicationRep')));
        var action = component.get('c.updateContactFields');
        action.setParams({"programRecipientList" : component.get('v.listOfProgramCommunicationRep')});
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var result = response.getReturnValue();
            var state = result.isSuccess;
            if (state) {
                var resMsg = result.message ;
                var resType = 'Success';
                setTimeout(function(){
                    var label = $A.get("$Label.c.Toast_Message_Label");
                    component.set("v.toastMsg" ,label);
                },2000);
                $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
                this.showToast(component, event, helper, resMsg, resType);
                $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire()

                console.log("Success ==>"+JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue()));
                
            } else{ 
                var errors = result.message;
                var resMsg = "Error message: " + errors;
                var resType = 'Error';
                this.showToast(component, event, helper, resMsg, resType);
                $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire()

            }
        });
        // enqueue the action
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
        
    },
    
    showToast : function(component, event, helper, resMsg, resType) {
        var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
        toastEvent.setParams({
            "title": resType,
            "message": resMsg,
            "type": resType
        });
        toastEvent.fire();
    },    
    
})
```

Here is the class :

```
public with sharing class GetProgramCommunicationRecipientsRecords {
    
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Program_Communication_Recipients__c> getProgramRecipients(Id recordId){
        System.debug('***enter first section*** ');
        //Get object Name using recordId.
        String sObjName = recordId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();
        System.debug('sObjName*** '+sObjName);
        
        List<Program_Communication_Recipients__c> programRecipients = new List<Program_Communication_Recipients__c>();
        
        //Check object Type
        if(sObjName == 'Program_Communication__c')
            programRecipients = [Select Name , Program_Communication__r.Learn_More_link__c , Program_Communication__r.Name ,Program_Communication__r.Program__r.Buyer__r.Name, Program_Communication__r.Program__r.Buyer__r.Account_Name_for_Communications__c, Program_Communication__r.Welcome_Message__c, Program_Communication__r.Logo_Public_Url__c, Program_Communication__r.URL_for_UI__c, Receipient__r.Name ,Receipient__r.contact__c , Receipient__c ,Welcome_Page_with_IDs__c, Program_Communication__r.From_Email__c, Program_Communication__r.Reply_to_Email__c From Program_Communication_Recipients__c Where Program_Communication__c =: recordId AND Date_Time_Email_Sent__c = null];
            
        else if(sObjName == 'Program_Communication_Recipients__c')
            programRecipients = [Select Name , Program_Communication__r.Learn_More_link__c , Program_Communication__r.Name ,Program_Communication__r.Program__r.Buyer__r.Name, Program_Communication__r.Program__r.Buyer__r.Account_Name_for_Communications__c, Program_Communication__r.Welcome_Message__c, Program_Communication__r.Logo_Public_Url__c, Program_Communication__r.URL_for_UI__c, Receipient__r.Name ,Receipient__r.contact__c , Receipient__c ,Welcome_Page_with_IDs__c, Program_Communication__r.From_Email__c, Program_Communication__r.Reply_to_Email__c  From Program_Communication_Recipients__c Where Id =: recordId AND Date_Time_Email_Sent__c = null];
            System.debug('***sObjNameInProgramCommRecipients '+sObjName );
        //Return
        return programRecipients;
    }
    

    @AuraEnabled
    public static ResponseWrapper updateContactFields(List<Program_Communication_Recipients__c> programRecipientList){
       System.debug('***enter 2nd section');
        //Create a instance of response wrapper for error handling
        ResponseWrapper response = new ResponseWrapper();
        
        try {
          
            //Check size of programRecipientList 
            if(programRecipientList.Size() > 0){
                
                //List to update Program Communication recipients
                List<Program_Communication_Recipients__c> updateProCommRec = new List<Program_Communication_Recipients__c>();
            
                //Map to update the Contact records
                Map<Id,Contact> mapContacts = new Map<Id,Contact>();
                
                //Traverse programRecipientList and fill updated contact list.
                for(Program_Communication_Recipients__c programRecipient : programRecipientList) {
                    
                    //Check if Contact is already have email notification
                    if(programRecipient.Receipient__c != null && programRecipient.Receipient__r.Contact__c != null
                        && !mapContacts.containsKey(programRecipient.Receipient__r.Contact__c)) {
                        
                        //Make instance of contact
                        Contact newContact = new Contact();

                        //Update date field after email sent.
                        updateProCommRec.add(new Program_Communication_Recipients__c(Id = programRecipient.Id , Date_Time_Email_Sent__c = System.now()));
                            
                        //Update Contact fields
                        newContact.Id = programRecipient.Receipient__r.Contact__c;
```

The whole first part of the class does not appear to be executing. The "System.debug('sObjName*** '+sObjName);" is not appearing in the debug log.

The first parts which are appearing is from the ResponseWrapper section.

Here is the beginning of the debug log. As you can see the first debug which appears is the '***enter 2nd section' line :

```
53.0 APEX_CODE,DEBUG;APEX_PROFILING,NONE;CALLOUT,FINEST;DB,NONE;NBA,NONE;SYSTEM,NONE;VALIDATION,NONE;VISUALFORCE,NONE;WAVE,NONE;WORKFLOW,NONE
14:00:38.0 (185924)|USER_INFO|[EXTERNAL]|00556000003xsjq|zzzzzz@zzzz.com|(GMT-04:00) Eastern Daylight Time (America/New_York)|GMT-04:00
14:00:38.0 (238696)|EXECUTION_STARTED
14:00:38.0 (244693)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|apex://GetProgramCommunicationRecipientsRecords/ACTION$updateContactFields
14:00:38.0 (6056581)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01p56000002GK0y|GetProgramCommunicationRecipientsRecords.updateContactFields(List<Program_Communication_Recipients__c>)
14:00:38.0 (6572427)|USER_DEBUG|[61]|DEBUG|***enter 2nd section***
```

Is there anything you can see which would prevent the first section from executing ? The Lightning Component action button is just referencing the class. It was working at one time.

Thank you for any input you can give.

Comment: Put some debug right at the start of the method. A null `recordId` would stop that debug being reached though you would still see some error info in the debug log.

Comment: I put in another debug right at the beginning of the method which is pure text and it also didn't show up in the debug log. I updated my post to show you.

Comment: OK. Presumably you've triple checked that the Lightning Component is referencing `GetProgramCommunicationRecipientsRecords. getProgramRecipients` and not some other Apex? Next step would be to do some client-side logging or debugging to check that the call is made. You can also look for the call in the browser Developer Tools Network tab.

Comment: The Lightning Component is referencing GetProgramCommunicationRecipientsRecords as the controller. I have included it in my post now.

Comment: I entered a System.debug('***enter 2nd section'); debug line into the 2nd method and included the beginning of the debug log to show that it is the first debug line that appears in the debug log. I updated my post. This is very frustrating. It's hard to troubleshoot something when it won't even run.

Comment: can you please add the javascript controller/Helper method code , which does invoking of first method of apex class?

Comment: @RanjitMishra - I just added the Helper from the Lightning Component to the post after the Controller. Thank you very much for your input.

Comment: @zoom_v - looking at your code everything looks fine to me, Just one thing i would say you should check that your aura controller or helper method should not contain any method with name "getProgramRecipients" which is basically same as apex class method. If that is the case then aura will remain in javascript instead of going to apex class.

Comment: @RanjitMishra - Thank you very much for your input.I have checked and that is not the case. The whole process is skipping into Apex properly. It just doesn't seem to be going to each method properly.UPDATE :I just went through some of the sub-classes in this process and entered a couple more debug lines and all of the sudden it showed up properly in debug ! But then I entered some more (static) debug lines-and it was back to where I was before ! I'm scratching my head because I can't get it to run again ! I am logging off and back on and trying to re-save classes just to save them but nothing.

Comment: @RanjitMishra - This apparently turned out to just be classes needing to be recompiled. It didn't make any sense. They had already been saved & deployed multiple times. I even got to be point of desperation where I was just logging off and back in and finally the methods just showed up ! I was using the same records for testing the whole time. I was doing exactly the same things. I was even using different laptops and re-saving on different laptops & logging on with different laptops. It really made no sense. Then I come in the next day and BOOM - it executed ! No idea. Thanks for your help !

Comment: @Zoom_v, Coding life sucks sometime. Good to hear that eventually the issue is resolved. Happy to help :)